# Laravel sum/count nested relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

i have a problem with simple relations.

Tables looks like that:

```
table players
id user_id game_id
1  2       1
2  5       1
3  3       1
4  4       2
5  2       2

table games
id result (win or lose)
1  1
2  0
```

What i need in result is:

```
Players Wins Losses
John    3    2
Philip  2    2
Jack    1    3
```

I tried alot of  queries but i cant get proper result.
This one

```
`"select * from `players` inner join `games` on `players`.`game_id` = `games`.`id`"`
```

This one is best i can do, but its raw and no idea how to rewrite it to DB:: or Eloquent. And its not grouping anyway.

Comment: Please post your model relationship code

Comment: please post what you have attempted so far

Answer (score 0):

you can directly count from relation with model.

```
$category = Category::find($id);
$category->children->count();
```

Comment: to get from User to Game they have to get through GamesAsHomePlayer (how they currently have it setup)